# Selective patterns with Matplotlib imshow without using patches

Tags: matplotlib, graphing

Is there a way to place patterns into selected areas on an imshow graph? To be precise, I need to make it so that, in addition to the numerical-data-carrying colored squares, I also have different patterns in other squares indicate different failure modes for the experiment (and also generate a key explaining the meaning of these different patterns). An example of a pattern that would be useful would be various types of crosshatches. I need to be able to do this without disrupting the main color-numerical data relationship on the graph.

Due to the back-end I am working within for the GUI containing the graph, I cannot utilize patches (they fail to pickle and make it from the back-end to the front-end via the multiprocessing package). I was wondering if anyone knew of another way to do this.

```
grid = np.ma.array(grid, mask=np.isnan(grid))
ax.imshow(grid, interpolation='nearest', aspect='equal', vmax = private.vmax, vmin = private.vmin)
# Up to here works fine and draws the graph showing only the data with white spaces for any point that failed
if show_fail and faildat != []:
    faildat = faildat[np.lexsort((faildat[:,yind],faildat[:,xind]))]
    fails = []
    for i in range(len(faildat)):  #gives coordinates with failures as (x,y)
        fails.append((faildat[i,1],faildat[i,0]))
    for F in fails:
         ax.FUNCTION NEEDED HERE
ax.minorticks_off()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(placex)))        
ax.set_yticks(range(len(placey)))
ax.set_xticklabels(placex)        
ax.set_yticklabels(placey, rotation = 0)
ax.colorbar()
ax.show()
```

Comment: I wrote the experimental pickling functionality. It may be we can fix the root problem so that you *can* use patches for this (which is kind of what they are designed for). Can you add some code which highlights the failing patches?

Comment: just put an add_patches where the FUNCTION NEEDED HERE is. I've been trying rectangles. That said, it's a specific issue with the package I am working with (pythics) so I am not sure how generally applicable it is. On the other hand, the errors are coming from the multiprocessing package being called by pythics, so it may be an underlying issue.

Comment: `p = patches.Rectangle(F,1,1,hatch='/',fill=False)`
`ax.add_patch(p)`
is what I had been trying